# How to solve this AttributeError in python?

Tags: python

Hi all I'm really new to python and am trying to build a simple RPG game. I'm having a problem creating a magic spelling system.

Everything works except for when I try to print the damage points caused by the magic spelling system.

```
    from classes.game import Person

    # Create magic
    magic = [{"name": "Fire", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60}, 
     {"name": "Thunder", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60}, 
     {"name": "Blizzard", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60}]

    # Instantiate people
    player = Person(460, 65, 60, 34, magic)

    print(player.generate_dmg()) # This Works
    print(player.generate_spell_dmg(0)) # This fails
```

Person Class:

```
    import random

    class Person:
        def __init__(self, hp, mp, atk, defense, magic):
            self.max_hp = hp
            self.hp = hp
            self.max_mp = mp
            self.mp = mp 
            self.atkl = atk - 10
            self.atkh = atk + 10
            self.defense = defense
            self.magic = magic 
            self.action = ["Attack", "Magic"]

        def generate_dmg(self):
            return random.randrange(self.atkl, self.atkh)

        def generate_spell_dmg(self, i):
            ml = self.magic[i]["dmg"] - 5
            mh = self.magic[i]["dmg"] + 5 
            return random.randrange(ml, mh)
```

I'm getting the following Error:

```
     55
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            
    Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-5-784d54c9b5c2> in <module>()
          8 print(player.generate_dmg())
          9 
    ---> 10 print(player.generate_spell_dmg(0))
         11 

    AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'generate_spell_dmg'
```

Comment: It works for me without modifying a single line

Comment: Same for me as ibarrond, just put it all in one file and it ran.

Comment: are you sure you saved your file?

Comment: Ditto for me. Works as intended

Comment: I ran this in Jupyter notebook and it kept telling me there's an attributeError...

Comment: Yes I've saved my file

Comment: Did you execute the part of the code the class is defined in after adding the generate_spell_dmg method?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: do you have some more function definitions in-between generate_dmg and generate_spell_dmg?

Comment: yes I've executed it. I'm using python 3

Comment: I also ran this in Jupyter Notebook and it worked flawlessly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna go for a wild guess here: If you import your module in a Jupyter Notebook, then modify it and try to import it again, Python detects that the module was already imported and thus doesn't update your module. The **solution** would be to **Restart the Kernel** every time you want to reimport a module.

Comment: I suggest you update your question with the information about running  the code in a Jupyter Notebook